# debugging two cortex elf files (bootloader and application)

Tags: visual-studio-code, cortex-m

I have an STM microcontroller and trying to use VS Code to use a debugger for the bootloader and application.  I have a launch configuration for each, but after launching the bootloader, I can't figure out how to load the elf file for the application once the bootloader jumps to the application code space.  Is it possible for VS Code to initially debug with one elf/launch configuration and then switch to another elf/launch configuration?  If so, how would I go about configuring VS Code to switch between the two during a debug session?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use gdb command symbol-file in the debug console of the vscode:

```
symbol-file C:/path_to_project/project.elf
or 
add-symbol-file C:/path_to_project/project.elf
```

and please load the symbol only after jump to application if you use symbol-file

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_14.html

or recommending a debugging extension for embedded system: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug

you may load the executables and symbol files using these attributes:

- loadFiles: to select the (multiple) target binary (hex) to download to flash
- symbolFiles: to load the (multiple) debug symbol to debug session

https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/blob/master/debug_attributes.md